# AndroidStudio - how to copy SharedPreferances file from intern to external storage using uri?

Tags: android-studio, file-copying

I like to copy (Backup & Restore) my SharedPreferences File to an external storage

the normal copy doesn't work, I thonk because of the new restriction since Android 10
oder 11

In manifest I set permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

the code with

```
copyFile(in, out);
```

worked internal, but external path not is not working

my example is to copy assent

```
private void copyAsset(String filename){


    String dirPath = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+"/MyFiles";
   //String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+"/TasmoRemote";

    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(filename);
        File outFile = new File(dirPath, filename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        copyFile(in, out);
        Toast.makeText(this, dirPath + "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

creating file using URI is also working, but I don't knwo how to combine it, that
I can just copy the ShardePreferences File to an external storage.

Does anyone know a way to solve my problem?

Thank you
Tacker